# Replace over multiple lines with javascript replace()

Tags: javascript, replace, flags

I need some help with replacing multiple lines in a javascript. 
I have read something about using flags, but I dont know how to implement them.

This is my current replace()

```
var res = str.replace(selectedText,'<b>' + selectedText + '</b>');
```

It is working for a single line, but not for multiple lines.

If selectedText was:

aaa
bbb

ccc

The result would be:

**aaa
bbb**

**ccc**

Any tips?

//Ambrose

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more on what you want. Also adding more code could be helpful, so we can more accurately help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `replace` a string for the first argument, only the first match is replaced. To replace *all* matches, you have to pass in an regular expression as the first argument, and use the `g` flag on it. This replaces all `a`s with `b`s:

```
var str = "a a a a";
str = str.replace(/a/g, 'b');
console.log(str); // "b b b b"
```

So you'll need to create a regular expression for `selectedText`. You can do that via `new RegExp(selectedText, "g")`:

```
var res = str.replace(new RegExp(selectedText, "g"),'<b>' + selectedText + '</b>');
```

...**but** if `selectedText` has any characters in it that have special meaning in a regular expression, you have to escape those. Sadly, JavaScript has no built-in function for doing that, but if you search around you can find several examples of functions to do it. [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) has some options as well.

If we use the `RegExp.escape` from [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/157247) *(it's a bit overkill, but fairly harmless in its overkill-ness)*:

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

...then:

```
var res = str.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(selectedText), "g"),'<b>' + selectedText + '</b>');
```

Comment: It should only replace the first match shouldnt it? As I put in selectedText and basically want back my entire text except that the selectedText now is bold.

Comment: @Ambrose: Ah, I misunderstood. There's nothing special about line breaks. If you're not seeing the text get replaced, then the text isn't exactly what you think it is. For instance, if your text is `"aaaa bbbb\ncccc"` but the string you're replacing that in is `"aaaa bbbb<br>cccc"` or even `"aaaa bbbb<p>cccc</p>"`, then of course it won't match and won't update. The flags you've heard about only affect the meaning of the special `^` and `$` markers in regular expressions; they wouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: Hmm ok, that makes sense. But should that really matter as I am basically replacing selectedText with selectedText + minor additions?

I am not trying to replace "aaa bbb\nccc"(=selectedText) with "aaa bbb <p>ccc". I am replacing it with "<b> aaa bbb\nccc (=selectedText) </b>". Am I not?

Comment: @Ambrose: Right. What I'm saying is that if you're not seeing a change, then `selectedText` isn't in the string. I was giving examples of how you might have `"aaaa bbbb\ncccc"` but the text in the string you're replacing is actually `"aaaa bbbb<br>cccc"` and so it doesn't match and doesn't get updated.